# can i apply OR condition here in mongoose (mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to update any one Key but I don't know how to give OR condition is their any way that I can add OR condition to update any one key or both key at same time.

```
const updateBlogs = async (req, res) => {
    const { blogId } = req.params;
    const re = /<("[^"]?"|'[^']?'|[^'">])*>/;

    if (re.test(req.params.blogTitle)) {
        sendError(400, "Unsuccessful", "Blog Title cannot be HTML", req, res);
    } else {
        try {
            let blog = await Blog.updateOne(
                { blogId },
                {
                    $set: {
                        blogTitle: req.body.blogTitle,
                        blogContent: req.body.blogContent,
                    },
                },
                { runValidators: true }
            );
            sendResponse(200, "Successfull", blog, req, res);
        } catch (err) {
            sendError(400, "Blog can't be updated by given id", err, req, res);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: When you say keys, are you referring to `blogTitle` and `blogContent`?

Comment: yes @MontgomeryWatts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the update document beforehand depending on what fields are available in the `req.body`.

Here's an example:

```
let update = {};
if (req.body.blogTitle) update.blogTitle = req.body.blogTitle;
if (req.body.blogContent) update.blogContent = req.body.blogContent;

let blog = await Blog.updateOne(
    { blogId },
    {
        $set: update,
    },
    { runValidators: true }
);
```

As you can see, the fields are set only if they're present in the request, and are passed to the update. Be aware that this solution assumes that at least one of the fields will be present -- if an empty update document is passed to `$set` you'll get an error.